# Django channels start runworker with same consumer multiple times and automatically init all workers

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-channels

I am trying to build up a more or less scalable infrastructure with django channels:

- I have a consumer called sendConsumer which is connected via wss to server A and everytime I send a signal to that consumer from django it forwards it to the server A.
- Then I have a consumer called receiveConsumer which is connected via wss to server B where I retrive thousends of events per second.

However now I want to scale this approach up and have multiple background consumers (so multiple wss connections to server B) and the documentation is unfortunally very quite about this.

And yes I really need django channels and not a task queue:
In my case django channels is the best approach rather than using celery or similar as I want to be able to send updates to the workers from a django view or a signal to update parameters on the fly.

My idea to solve that issue was to create multiple systemd files that have their own environment variables and therefore every worker can start with its own id.

In addition with that I modified the apps.py to send an inital message to the worker to basically wake it up and run some init actions.

The issue is that I can't route it to a specific worker and always send the signal to the same one. I also can't just set a group name as `runworker` doesn't trigger the `__init__`  and therefore I can't assign group names to route to.

So one solution would be to add multiple names to the asgi.py configuration so I would have
receive-connector-1 receive-connector-2... but this seems like a very bad practice to me.
Is there a good approach for this issue?

asgi.py:

```
    {
        "http": get_asgi_application(),
        "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter(
                websocket_urlpatterns
            )
        ),
        "channel": ChannelNameRouter({
            "send-connector": SendConsumer.as_asgi(),
            "receive-connector": ReceiveConsumer.as_asgi()
        }),
    }
)
```

systemd:

```
Description=start receive-consumer
Wants=network.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment="SHARD_ID=<ID>"
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c 'until ping -c1 google.com; do sleep 1; done;'
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 manage.py runworker receive-consumer
Restart=always
LimitNOFILE=16384

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

apps.py

```
class ConnectorConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'Connector'

    def ready(self):
        shard_id = os.environ.get('SHARD_ID')
        if shard_id is not None:
            channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
            async_to_sync(channel_layer.send)(
                "receive-connector",
                {
                    'type': 'create_conduit',
                    'data': {
                        'SHARD_ID': shard_id
                    }
                }
            )
```